# Select the values from custom list using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Custom List ( List<GetDrpList> ) 
 
The web-service return List<GetDrpList> to ajax success.

```
public struct GetDrpList 
{
    int setIndex;
    string setName;
    int formIndex;
    string formName;
 }
```

My Ajax Success Function

```
success: function(data) {
   var lst = data.d;
},
```

My Custom List is like this

```
index     setIndex  setName   formIndex   formName

[0]    =  0,        OAI,      0,          OAI_1
[1]    =  0,        OAI,      1,          OAI_2
[2]    =  0,        OAI,      2,          OAI_3
[3]    =  1,        EPP,      0,          EPP_1
[4]    =  1,        EPP,      1,          EPP_2
```

Now I need to select from this list unique setIndex, setName that means
0, OAI
1, EPP
and also select the formIndex,formName based on setIndex that means
if setIndex=0
0, OAI_1
1, OAI_2
2, OAI_3

Comment: What is your output when you do JSON.stringify(data.d);

Comment: I'd recommend returning JSON, then on the clientside doing a $.parseJSON(data.d)...this will get you your array of objects.

Comment: Are you setting the setIndex to a DOM element? When/where are you 'selecting' the values?